Quantum Cryptography without Bell's Theorem -- Brassard - Bennett - Mermin
It is an old paper but I'm trying to understand one of their argument. They say that if
$$U|u\rangle |a\rangle = |u\rangle |a^\prime\rangle \ \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ \ U|v\rangle |a\rangle = |v\rangle |a^{\prime\prime}\rangle$$
then since $U$ is unitary
$$ \langle u|v\rangle  = \langle a| \langle u|v\rangle |a\rangle = \langle a^{\prime}| \langle u|v\rangle |a^{\prime\prime} \rangle$$
This is Equation (4).
The first equality is simple: $\langle u|v\rangle  = \langle a| (\langle u|v\rangle |a\rangle)$, since $\langle a|a\rangle = 1$.
Then, $\langle a| \langle u|v\rangle |a\rangle = \langle a| \langle u| U^* U |v\rangle |a\rangle = \langle a| \langle u| U^* |v\rangle |a^{\prime\prime}\rangle$.
The last step should be $\langle a| \langle u| U^* = (U |a \rangle |u \rangle)^*$. I do not see how to conclude from here. The Hermitian transpose on the Kronecker product of two matrices does not commute the matrices.
Where is my error?

please edit the post to link any paper you're referring to

Whether the conjugation transposes tensor factors or not, I think, depends on the convention.
The authors chose to write a bra in $(\mathcal{V} \otimes \mathcal{A})^*$ as $\left<a\right| \left<u\right|$ for $\left|a\right> \in \mathcal{A}$, $\left|u\right> \in \mathcal{V}$, and in this notation conjugation transposes the tensor factors.
If we use the notation where the tensor factors are not transposed, the equation will be something like $$\left<u|v\right> = \left<a|a\right>\left<u|v\right> = \left<u,a|v,a\right> = \left<u,a|U^\dagger U|v,a\right> = \left<u,a'|v,a''\right> = \left<u|v\right>\left<a'|a''\right>$$

I would like to add some comments. Relying on the following consistent and classical conventions:
(1) $|a\rangle^* = \langle a|$,
(2) $|ab\rangle = |a\rangle \otimes |b\rangle$,
(3) $(|a\rangle \otimes |b\rangle)^* = \langle a| \otimes \langle b|$,
and (4) $(w \otimes x) \cdot (y \otimes z) = wy \otimes xz$, if the dimensions of the vectors/matrices are compatible -- mixed product rule, effectively your derivation is the solution.

In the textbook, they mention that $ \langle u|v \rangle $ cannot be 0. Below are the steps taken to get their result.
We know that $ \langle a|a \rangle = 1. $

$ \langle u|v \rangle = \langle a| (\langle u|v \rangle |a \rangle ) $

$ \langle a| \langle u|v \rangle |a \rangle = \langle a| (u|U^\dagger + U|v \rangle |a \rangle = \langle a| \langle u|U^\dagger|v \rangle |a'' \rangle  $


Since $ U^\dagger U = I $, the equation hasn't necessarily changed.

$ \langle u|v \rangle \Rightarrow \langle U (|u \rangle |a') | U (|v \rangle |a') \rangle $

Plugging in $ U(|u \rangle |a\rangle) = |u \rangle |a'\rangle $ and $ U(|v \rangle |a'\rangle = |v \rangle |a''\rangle $:

$ \langle u|v \rangle \Rightarrow \langle (|u \rangle |a'\rangle) | I (|v \rangle |a''\rangle) \rangle $

$ \langle u|v \rangle = \langle u|v \rangle \cdot \langle a'' |a'' \rangle $


After separating, we know that $ \langle u|v \rangle $ cannot be 0 as stated above, so:
$$ \langle a' |a'' \rangle = 1. $$
